# Automatically update apps in iTunes

Tags: itunes, ios-appstore, auto-update

Since iOS7 installed applications on iPhone and iPad are automatically updated. Is there any way to also **automatically** update the applications in the iTunes library (either direct or indirect via an iOS device)?

Right now I have a iTunes 12 libraries that contains music, applications etc. that automatically synchronizes with a couple of devices (all on iOS8) via wifi. The devises all have automatic updates for applications enabled. While the updates are downloaded on the devices, the updates are apparently not synchronized back to iTunes. Likewise iTunes does not automatically download available updates, updates are shown in the 'Avilable Updates' tab, but not downloaded.

Comment: There currently is no setting to auto-update apps.

Comment: Is there at least a way to get the applications that where updated on the iOS device synchronized back into the library?

Comment: Yes - sync your device in iTunes. The problem doing it this way is it takes a while for data to transfer over USB.

Comment: Via USB:

File > Devices > Transfer Purchases from <iOS Device>

Once the apps are transferred to iTunes, they should be able to update on your other devices via WiFi.